# How to convert sql command to laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent

Here is my code using mysql command

```
SELECT * FROM `order_list` WHERE currentdate like '%12%' and currentdate like '%2017%'
```

but Im having a problem converting it into laravel eloquent.

```
$orderlists = Orderlist::where('currentdate', 'like', "%$month%")
                                    ->where('currentdate', 'like', "%$year%")
                                    ->get();
```

is this correct?thanks

Comment: It's bad idea to search dates with `LIKE`. mysql has `YEAR()` or `MONTH()` function which fit better.

Comment: That could potentially return the 12th January 2017 (12/01/2017), something to think about.

Comment: my date format in db is like `mm/dd/yyyy`

Comment: Could you please provide a sample @u_mulder?thanks

Comment: In `currentdate like '%12%'` you search what? 12 as a day, or 12 as a month (december).

Comment: `%12%` is a month @u_mulder

Comment: Please, make an effort and use a search engine. You will find plenty of answers.

Comment: Is your `currentdate` column on the database a varchar? Or is it a date/time datatype?

Comment: `currentdate` is a varchar @MarkBaker

Comment: So why are you using a varchar to store dates when you should be using a date datatype? This is going to cause you a lot of problems in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$orderlists = Orderlist::whereMonth('currentdate', 'LIKE','%'.$month.'%')
                                ->whereYear('currentdate', 'LIKE', '%'.$year.'%')
                                ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use your raw sql query as shown below

```
$orderlists = DB::select("SELECT * FROM `order_list` WHERE currentdate like '%12%' and currentdate like '%2017%'");
```